# Xamarin UWP and Azure Mobile Services Offline SQLite Sync - problems when building in Relase mode with .Net Native Toolchain on

Tags: sqlite, xamarin.forms, uwp, azure-mobile-services

We have a problem when we build our app in Release mode with .Net Native Toolchain on.

MobileServiceClient.SyncContext.PendingOperations then returns -1 instead of 0 when there are no Pending Operations which result in that offline functionality no longer works (no items that are inserted when you are offline are sent over to the server).

The same phenomenon is described here:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-services/issues/890

We have tested with Visual Studio Update 2 and also with Visual Studio Update 3, but unfortunately, the problem remains in that version.

However, we have noticed that if we set "Optimize code" = false the offline functionality works, but then we instead get the following errors when Windows App Certification Kit tests have been completed.

"AppName" takes a dependency on Microsoft .Net Native Framework Package 1.x framework but is missing the framework dependency declaration in the manifest.

and

API CoCreateInstance in api-ms-win-core-com-l1-1-0.dll is not supported for this application type. "AppName.dll" calls this API.

If anyone has a solution for this, we would be very grateful!

Comment: This has been a common theme with UWP. Please make sure to also post this on MSDN so they are tracking the issue.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of a member from the .NET Native runtime and compiler team (Many thanks) we have been able to troubleshoot the problem and come up with a workaround!

We have worked around this issue by adding this to Properties\Default.rd.xml file:

```
<Library Name="Newtonsoft.Json"> <Assembly Name="Newtonsoft.Json" DoNotOptimize="true"DoNotInline="true" /></Library>​
```

This instructs the optimizer to ignore all of the types/methods inside of Newtonsoft.Json.

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that you reposted on the Azure Forums as well.  I asked a few follow-up questions there and will answer your query there.  We can cross-post the eventual answer if you like.